# Is this port broken?

Tags: usb, hardware-failure, port

The bottom of this looks like a normal USB port, corresponding to the symbol shown, but what is the top?  Is it a broken USB port?

Why is there that one pin sticking out by itself on the right, while there seem to be other pins that are covered?

[image]
[image]

This was on a Dell laptop, though not a Latitude D820.

Comment: The symbols to the side of the top port show a USB symbol above a power line symbol (power line over dashes). I believe some laptops had an extra "power" port for high powered USB devices but can't find a reputable source to  verify.

Comment: The Dell D820 has one of these ports and list it as an extra power port for USB: https://www.google.co.uk/search?sclient=tablet-gws&client=firefox-b&biw=960&bih=116&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=dell+d820+USB+power&oq=dell+d820+USB+power&gs_l=tablet-gws.3...95949.107674.0.108097.42.23.1.1.1.0.489.2626.1j13j1j1j1.17.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..24.10.1504...0j0i67k1j30i10k1.k-DFGAN_zs8#imgrc=b6IYDGlKs7asUM%3A

Answer (score 1):

It is fine.  The top part is extra power pins used for devices/peripherals that need more power than USB alone provides.

Answer (score -1):

It's not a broken USB port. It's actually fully intact, but a different thing. However, I'm not confident that it's a power port alone. What is the make / model of the thing you've taken a picture of?